# How to redirect to a newly created object in Django without a Generic View's post_save_redirect argument

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to redirect a user to a newly created object's `object.get_absolute_url()` after saving a form. I'm not using a generic view, so I can't use the `post_save_redirect` argument. The relevant portion of the `view` is like so:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('story_detail', args=(story.user, story.id)))
```

Now how would I get at the `story` object between the `form.save()` and the `HttpResponseRedirect` so that I can do the `reverse` lookup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `ModelForm`'s save method returns the newly created model instance. In your case, this means you should be able to work with the following:

```
if form.is_valid():
    story = form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('story_detail', args=(story.user, story.id)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the reverse and redirect

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse

# inside def
  if form.is_valid():
    story = form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Story created successfully!')

    return redirect(reverse('story_detail', kwargs={'story':story.id}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers, you can now just call `redirect` to an object, which is going to look for the `get_absolute_url` method of it. So if you have that set, just write:

```
return redirect(obj)
```