# How to redirect to a newly created object in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to redirect to the created object by filling the form below.

I've tried the solutions that I found on these posts:

[How to redirect to a newly created object in Django without a Generic View's post_save_redirect argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943510/how-to-redirect-to-a-newly-created-object-in-django-without-a-generic-views-pos)

and here:

[Redirection after creating an object, Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935385/redirection-after-creating-an-object-django)

Sometimes it just don't redirect and some other times it says

> "local variable 'property' referenced before assignment"

was not initiated. What am I doing wrong here?

```
# views.py
def add_property(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        property_add_form = PropertyAddForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if property_add_form.is_valid():
            property = property_add_form.save()
            # formset = ImageFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=property)
            # if formset.is_valid():
            print("Sucesso")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('properties:property_detail', kwargs={'property':property.id}))

    else:
        property_add_form = PropertyAddForm()
        print("Error")

    context = {
        'property_form':property_add_form,
        'title':"Add Property",
    }

    return render(request, 'properties/add-property.html', context)
```

.

```
#urls.py
    url(r'^add-property/', views.add_property, name='add_property'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.PropertyDetailView.as_view(),name='property_detail'),
```

The traceback:

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/envs/dapims3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/envs/dapims3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/envs/dapims3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/luissilva/Desktop/DAPIM/DAPIMS_Django/DAPIMS/properties/views.py"
>   in add_property
>     67.         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('property:property_detail',
>   kwargs={'property':property.id}))
>
> Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /properties/add-property/
>   Exception Value: local variable 'property' referenced before
>   assignment

Comment: can you show your url for property_details

Comment: Please show the traceback.

Comment: @user11418935 I've edited and included the property_details url. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've added the traceback on my last edit. Could you please check it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code as shown wouldn't give that error. Are you sure the indentation is exactly as you have it in your code? For example, might that `return HttpResponseRedirect` be one indent to the left? If you're using an old version of Python, are you sure you haven't mixed tabs and spaces?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I had one tab to the left on the return Http... Now it is exactly like it is on this post. But now it doesn't return me anywhere, it just reloads the page and don't post anything

Comment: Presumably then the form is not valid. Are you displaying the form errors? Show your template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've made it work with this: `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('properties:property_detail', args=[property.id]))`I've changed it and it started working. Don't really know if this was the problem but it's working now.. Thanks for your help!!